# How do I get meaningful error messages in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, errordocument, default-document

I have a classic ASP website that is crashing in IIS7.
It is crashing because IIS doesn't allow file uploads greater than a certain size. I know this because files below about 200k work fine.
I removed the Status Code 500 error in IIS but I still don't get a file name and the line where my code failed as I do when running locally.

Instead I get:

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
occurred.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error."

See [http://adcore-com-au.si-sv3956.com/admin/edit_options.asp](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110012654/http://adcore-com-au.si-sv3956.com:80/admin/edit_options.asp) for an example.

See http://www.yart.com.au/admin/edit_options.asp for what it should look like.

How do I get a file name and the line where my code failed?

Here are my IIS settings:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yart.com.au](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/errors.png))</sub>

Comment: Viewing the site from the computer that's running IIS tends to show more error details (assuming the default settings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login as an admin on the IIS server, open IIS 7 Manager, the open the Asp icon under the Web site you want to change the error messages for (it'll be on the right with all the other icons; it's the first one).

Scroll down and change **Send Errors To Browser** to True.  Might have to `iisreset`, not sure.

Comment: After you get it working you might want to set it back to not sending errors to the browser.

Comment: Yup, Microsoft disabled error output by default so that sensitive information about your configuration (databases, IPs, paths, etc.) is not disclosed to your visitors.